# rails form_for edit text area

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb, form-for

I would like to know if there is a way to add buttons in form_for so they will edit text_area.

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
<div class="field
<%= f.label :content %><br>
<%= f.text_area :content, :size => "70x20" %>
</div>
```

this is part of my form_for and I would like to add some buttons with HTML tags which would insert text inside text_area like

```
<b></b> <i></i>
```

Is it possible ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for javascript. There are a lot of different resources to check out online.

There are also a lot of prebuilt ones. You can check out (in no particular order):

- http://ckeditor.com/
- http://jejacks0n.github.io/mercury/
- http://www.tinymce.com/

In very basic javascript, you could do something like:

```
<%= link_to("Bold", '#', onclick: "myFunction(); return false") %>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var textArea = document.getElementById('post_content');
  textArea.value += "<b></b>";
}
</script>
```

Comment: You made my day sir!
This is exactly what I needed, I would upvote, but I cant because of my low reputation, thank you.